# Typescript union equivalent in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I've gotten used to thinking with typescript, and I'm trying to store the following with mongoose.

```
interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

interface Line {
   start: Point;
   end: Point;
}

interface Arc {
    center: Point;
    radius: number;
    startAngle: number;
    sweep: number;
}

type Feature = Line | Arc;
```

Is there a way to represent Feature in mongoose without using Mixed? I don't want to lose the benefits of the schema, but I need to define a few different types to fill the same child attribute.

Comment: This is rather late, but have you by chance figured this out?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the way I got around this was by using a interface that can represent line and arc, basically I have a list of points of x, y, r based on the DSTV (.nc1) standard relevant to the application I am working on. My idea when I rework this is to have two seperate lists lines, and arc, and to give them each their own schema. Then I will put them back together using an "index" field representing their position in my origional list of features.